# Drupal 7 header

Tags: drupal-7

This may sound like a very obvious question for drupalistas, but for the life of me, I can't figure out where the header element is so I can rearrange it to put the search above the main menu. I am using a subtheme off of a very stark theme called framework.

I see this line:

I want to know where the code resides so I can set the blocks to print the search block first and the main menu second.

Answer (score 2):

You can move your blocks around in the `page.tpl.php` template file.

If you've not done so already copy `modules/system/page.tpl.php` to `YOUR_THEME/templates/page.tpl.php` and clear your cache out.

Open the `page.tpl.php` file and you'll see where your blocks are printed out.

e.g. `<?php print render($page['header']); ?>`

Will print your header block out.

From there you can put blocks in any order you want.

To reorder in a block, go to admin -> blocks and use the arrows on the left of each block to drag them into the order you want them to be rendered. Remember to save your order and you should be set.

Comment: But within that block, I have both my menu and my search block. How do I rearrange those?